# Is a sent email in someone else’s inbox subject to data subject rights of the sender?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, data, subject-access-request

Suppose Bob emails Alice, and both use Hotmail for their e-mail provider. Bob then deletes the message from his sent mail folder. Could Bob issue a subject access request (SAR) to Hotmail for the message (provided it is in fact still) held by Hotmail in Alice's inbox?

Or suppose Charlotte emails Dave, who uses a different email provider from him. Could she submit an SAR to Dave’s email provider for the message she sent to him, provided it is held by them?

Comment: What is SAR in this context?  Because I'm pretty sure it's not Search And Rescue.  And what is the legal context for these actions?

Comment: My email client (which is distinct from the service provider) has an option whether to store only the email headers locally or the entire email. If the latter, how is Bob's request anything to do with the email service provider? To misquote a saying, *email in haste, repent at leisure.* With messaging services such as Whatsapp, I think there is an option to delete messages from the whole group, but if someone has made a copy, that's too late.

Comment: Who has said anything about email clients? Furthermore lest you forget this is the age of webmail.

Comment: There is no relevant difference between webmail and my email client. Both provide third-party access to the email account. My point remains: how is copy saved locally subject to access by the service provider? The situation is similar to using speech: once you have said something, it can't be *unsaid*.

Comment: @WeatherVane I fail to understand what you're saying. If the message is in possession of the ISP, via webmail, a subpoena or search warrant could be used to obtain it. In fact, many countries have legislation which [require ISPs retain e-mails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_retention) for some period of time. The question here is whether GDPR SAR is a means.

Comment: @WeatherVane web-based e-mail is stored on the provider's servers. Even if a sender deletes a sent email from their records, it may still exist on the provider's servers if the recipient has not deleted it. Likewise, even if both sender and receiver delete it from their own mailboxes, it may _still_ exist on the provider's servers.

Answer (score 9):

An Art 15 Subject Access Request (SAR) “shall not adversely affect the rights and freedoms of others.”

It would be a grave violation of privacy for an email provider to search its users' account contents. It is therefore likely that the email provider would refuse to fulfil that subject request, unless required to perform a search via a court order. Instead, the SAR could be directed to the account holder (Alice or Dave), if they are subject to the GDPR.

Depending on the exact legal framework, emails might be protected under confidentiality of communications rules, making such searches similarly illegal to wiretapping. At least in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), I am fairly certain that an email provider would be criminally liable if they were to disclose emails from their users' email accounts to a third party.

Comment: But the e-mail doesn't affect the privacy of "others" as the person who sent it is requesting it. Metadata, like the time and date it was opened, may have concerns, but not the content of the e-mail itself.

Comment: @user71659 The act of searching the account in itself threatens the account holder's privacy. The result would also disclose whether the recipient had already deleted that email.

Comment: For your first point, I don't understand. The requester knows the e-mail was received, via SMTP, "searching" doesn't disclose any information. Whether the ISP has the e-mail and whether the recipient deleted it is metadata and is often uncorrelated, given legal requirements for ISP data retention and operational needs (backups).

Comment: Yes I agree with @user71659’s nitpicks, I think they represent questions unaddressed and remaining to be answered.

Comment: Does this imply that one’s own email account’s contents can be subject to a SAR even if they are accessible to the data subject through other means?

Comment: @Seekinganswers They can (as per Data Portability), but I'm fairly sure "Your emails are available over IMAP; if you have trouble accessing your account please let us know" is a valid response to such a SAR.

Comment: I think you are falling into the same trap as the OP, thinking that "user's email accounts" is an existing thing. It is just a presentation of data. An SAR does not target representation of data, but data itself.

Comment: "is a valid response to such a SAR": no, it's not. The point of an SAR is to find out if a company holds data that I *cannot* see. A company telling me their external representation to their customer is the same as their internal data structure is a liar. Plain and simple. For example you can delete all kinds of stuff from your UI, but the company will need to keep stuff for tax purposes, even if you don't want to see it anymore. It might need to keep communication for a certain time according to laws for criminal investigations. Your action of "deleting a mail" is *not* deleting the mail.

Comment: Yes and furthermore, is a data subject not entitled to specify what formats in which they would like their data access request fulfilled?

Comment: @Seekinganswers Art 12(1) mentions that a data subject can request the information to be provided orally, but otherwise expects that information to be in written or electronic form, as “appropriate”. I would expect appropriateness to depend on both the controller's and subject's context, so that a subject cannot mandate arbitrary formats.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The right to data portability and the right to access are distinct but overlapping. I agree that "we have IMAP" is a great response to a data portability request, though.

Comment: @nvoigt I understand your point, but the email provider will primarily process the emails as data relating to the recipient's account. This requires further analysis to understand to which degree the provider is the data controller for the processing of these emails, and to which degree the emails are processed as relating to the sender. I have no doubt that there will be some such processing (e.g. in the context of making per-sender statistics for spam filtering purposes), but otherwise things are more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer and I am not aware of such a case being decided in court yet. So this i my interpretation of the law:

> Suppose Bob emails Alice, and both use Hotmail for their e-mail provider. Bob then deletes the message from his sent mail folder.

You are assuming the inner workings of Hotmail. The law does not care what is visible in your "sent mail" folder. The law cares about what is in Hotmails databases.

> Could Bob issue a subject access request (SAR) to Hotmail for the message

Yes, Bob could. If this email Bob wrote is still saved in Hotmails system in connection to Bobs personal data (in this case their email address in the "from" field clearly identifying it as valid personal data).

> (provided it is in fact still) held by Hotmail in Alice's inbox?

Again, you are assuming Hotmails data structure is an exact copy of your user interface. I can guarantee you, it is not. Whether it is visible in Alice's inbox is not relevant here. The only relevant point is whether PII was saved. It was, so an SAR should be able to retrieve it. Even if the email is no longer visible in *either* persons inbox, if it is still held in Hotmails database, it is subject to an SAR.

So with the SAR, no data about Alice would be given out. As the sender (or even receiver) of the mail, you already know it's contents, and you will only get to know whether hotmail still holds a copy of it. That says nothing about whether Alice read it, deleted it, printed it out and put it on display. Anything. It doesn't even say if Hotmail ever delivered it to her or if their email address even exists at Hotmail. Privacy of Alice is not breached here.

> Or suppose Charlotte emails Dave, who uses a different email provider from him. Could she submit an SAR to Dave’s email provider for the message she sent to him, provided it is held by them?

Yes, she could. Assuming she can prove that the PII (email address in the "from" field) is hers, she should get that email as a reply to the SAR.

---

Now, these were the clear cut cases. Where obvious PII in a field to hold that PII was concerned. It does get muddier down the road. What if Alice forwards the mail, and her mail program puts Bob's original sender email in the emails message text like "forwarded from Bob@example.com:". Is that still PII? It certainly still is Bob's email address that identifies Bob. But it is not in a field that identifies it as an email address to Hotmail. Hotmail is not required to search their customers non-PII fields (so any field that the provider did not ask for PII and is not using for purposes that would make it obvious they expect PII, for example "favorite pizza toping" or "message text") for accidential PII insertion. A SAR is about what *Hotmail* knows about you, not what Alice or the person she forwards this information too, knows about you. To Hotmail, this is message text. Could it potentially contain PII? Sure. Literally anything *could*. Do they know it does? No. That is what counts.

Lets take an example here. 1673. That is a random number I just typed. By the nature of 4 digit numbers only being available for 10000 unique instances, I can practially guarantee you that this is somebodies credit card PIN. So is it PII? If I enter it into a field where the data holder *knows* it's a credit card PIN, sure. Right now, in this post? No. Even if someone reads this post and goes "what, wait, how did they know *my* PIN?!?" It's not PII. It's just a number. Only the accompanying information that this number indeed *is* somebodies PIN would make it PII.

A good example of this might be Facebook or other invasive no-privacy corporate entities. If they *do* parse message texts, and they *do* have a table that says "this message from Alice contained Bob's email address" then that could be part of an SAR. I guess a judge would have to decide where Alice's rights to privacy end and Bob's start to take priority. My personal guess is that if Alice *agreed* to have her data spyed on this way by their message service, they would side with Bob, who is not even a party to that contract and had his PII taken and saved without his consent.

Comment: @Jen a field that is not *supposed* to hold PII. For example your email address is PII. Now if I ask you for your favorite color (not PII) and you enter your email address, while your email address *is* PII, the fact that you entered it where it wasn't expected means the data owner has no idea it is PII. And they are not required to make sure you don't enter your email in the "favorite color" field.

Comment: Same goes for other things. They need to be PCI compliant to save credit card information. But they don't need to be PCI compliant to save your favorite movie and it isn't their fault if instead of "Romeo & Juliet" you entered your credit card information.

Comment: I'm a litte confused here... if I had said non-firearms aren't covered by firearm regulations, would you ask me to explain what a non-firearm is and explain why they aren't covered by firearm regulations?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my answer? non-PII fields are relevant (and might be returned upon request), but if the data holder cannot identify it as PII, they cannot (and are not legally required to) identify it. For example if I identify as the owner of Charlie@example.com, they should give me all data they have on me. They are not required to scan all their data for connections they have not made. They are not required to scan all "What's your favorite movie" fields of all their users to check if one contains my email address. That is not how PII works.

Comment: Okay, so not having yet fully read your answer nor having read any of the comments under it, here is what I have to say: I respect its formidable argument and have upvoted it accordingly. I also agree with it in that it is how I think the law should be applied, and yet I also wonder if there are any strong counter arguments as I am interested in as many different competing perspectives as possible in the marketplace of ideas. So I have abstained just yet from accepting it as the correct answer. However I do have one nitpick: I would be surprised if hotmail does not save two independent

Comment: duplicate copies of the message in relation to bob’s and Alice’s respective user accounts. Though in general I agree with both the correctness and the assessment of supposed importance of the distinction between how data is held and represented in user interface. I would very much hope that the law would not be applied in such an inconsistent way so as to obscure and overlook this distinction in the interest of appeasing common perception and the expedience for the vast cloud computing or “SaaS” technology sector. We may recall that such prominent firms as meta have already deemed gdpr complia

Comment: nce to be so impractical and inexpedient to their interests as to be worth brazenly flouting and as I understand even worth  fighting to defend their position on this brazen non compliance in court.

Comment: I think this answer could be greatly improved by using the GDPR "personal data" concept instead of "PII". I agree with the premise that it matters what the controller "knows" about the subject, which I'd phrase as: it matters whether the controller is processing personal data about the data subject, not just data that could also be processed as personal data. On the other hand, I'd point to Art 11(2), which would require the controller to search for the subject's data if the subject provides enough info to enable identification – kind of going against the concept of a "PII field".

Comment: @amon I doubt that I am the only one who is looking forward to your own answer to this question.